# Unity - Unexpected Symbol '{'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, c#-3.0

Here is my code Unity says-"Unexpected Symbol {"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Camera : MonoBehaviour {
//variables

    public Transform player;
    public float smooth = 0.3f;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;  //camera velocity to zero with variable velocity

    //Methods
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3();
        pos.x = player.position.x;  // postion on x axis = player
        pos.z = player.position.z - 7f;  //-7f to move the camera a little back from player position
        pos.y = player.position.y;
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp{ transform.position, pos,ref velocity, smooth};
        //smoothdamp is a function of vector 3 which smoothenes the movement
    }   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: use parenthesis when calling a method: `transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp (transform.position, pos, ref velocity, smooth);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rufus L is correct.

You used braces instead of parenthesis in the SmoothDamp method, please see how to use it here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html

In C# we use braces to show a block of code belonging to a statement, e.g. an if blocks, using blocks, method blocks, class blocks, etc.

braces are also used on object instantiation (when the constructor is called) to initialize variables, e.g.

```
Person john = new Person(){ Name = "John" };
```

In short, braces define scope where values defined within them go out of scope when the braces terminate unless those values exist elsewhere.

Parenthesis however are used for multiple other things but none of them to indicate scope. They are used to indicate arguments, casts, to alter the order in which mathematical expressions occur, etc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/invocation-operator

In short, be careful not to confuse () and {}+

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis "()" when calling a method not braces "{}".

CHANGE THIS:

transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp{ transform.position, pos,ref velocity, smooth};

TO THIS:

transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp( transform.position, pos, ref velocity, smooth);